# Conditional If Conditions... Possible?

Tags: php

Sorry, I am pretty new to php.

Is something like this possible?

```
if ( if ($clauseA) { A } if ($clauseB) { || B } ) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

What I want to do is if $clauseA is true, include A in condition and if $clauseB is true, then include || B (OR and B) in condition.

Is there any solid way to achieve this?

Comment: what is A? and what is B? are they variables, statements, something else?

Comment: what is `|| B` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to do this....

1. If Clause A is true, evaluate A as part of your condition, OR
2. If Clause B is true, evaluate B as part of your condition:

Code:

```
if (($clauseA && A) || ($clauseB && B)) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical `or`, aliased `||`, always works this way. If the first conditional expression does not evaluate to true, the second conditional expression is not tested or executed.

The same goes for `and` (`&&`), it will not continue if the first expression evaluates to false.

**Update:**
In fact, I think I just understood the question. :)

```
if ( ($clauseA && A) || ($clauseB && B) ) {
    // A and B will only be checked if the appropriate clause is true, otherwise they are ignored.
}
```

Comment: `or` and `||` have a slightly different behaviour in php. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @Cobra_Fast The symbolic variants have greater precedence. How else are they different?

Comment: That is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast They have greater precedence over each other. You will only notice it if you mix them up. You don't really mix 'em together, do you? o_O

Comment: @StevenMoseley Yes, since it's the only right answer. Yours takes the cake though, you got a +1 from me. :)

Comment: Looks like it could serve the purpose. I'll get back as soon as I check this.

Answer (score 0):

`if ($clauseA) {
 if ($clauseB) {
  B
 } else {
 A
 }
 // Do stuff
}`

Comment: Redundant logic. Why check for `$clauseA` twice? You just did that.

Comment: He said he is new to php, and he wanted "to do is if $clauseA is true, include A in condition and if $clauseB is true, then include || B (OR and B) in condition." and I think if I write like this, it is more understandable for him.

Answer (score 0):

In boolean logic, this is expressed as:

```
if (($clauseA && $a) || ($clauseB && $b))
```

Or some variation thereof, depending on what exactly you want to do. The point being, you can express it using a combination of `&&` and `||`, without `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If A and B are boolean conditions that only have to be true if $clauseA or $clauseB are true as well, just rewrite your condition like this:

```
if( (!$ClauseA || $A) && (!$ClauseB || $B)) {
    // Do Stuff
}
```

I just applied De Morgan's laws (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) to accomplish this.

Comment: You don't not have a very non negated simple way to positively not express that... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the following:
$clauseA might be true and/or $clauseB may be true, but both can be false:

```
if ((($clauseA || $clauseB) && A) || ($clauseB && B))
{ 
    // Doing some stuff     
}
```